# Asp.net MVC2 login to MVC5 login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-5

I got a MVC2 project that I would like to upgrade to MVC5. 
I would like to use the new asp.net owin and asp.net identity. 
How ever if I would go ahead and make a new asp.net MVC5 project I would probably need to redo my database. And my database is rather big and complex, would it be possible somehow to generate new controllers from my existing database ?

Or would it just be easier to stick with the current login system I already use ? (asp.net mvc2)

Comment: The old – membership/role/… provider based – system is still supported in MVC5 so you can continue using that. I would get the MVC version updated and working first and then think about how much refactoring (and data conversion) will be needed to change authentication/authorisation systems.

Comment: NB. remember MVC5 uses .NET 4.6. it is ASP.NET 5 and *MVC6* that use .NET Core (it would have been really helpful for MS to call it ASP.NET 6 to help avoid confusion).

Comment: @Richard thanks for your reply. As of right now I did just make a new MVC 5 application and copied / paste my old models / controllers. That will have to work for now.